# Query of DateTime field with LINQ is throwing an exception in C# but not in VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, datatable, vb.net-to-c#

My solution contains VB.NET and C# Projects. I`m querying **the same DataTable** (only the DataTable parameter name is different in both functions below) with LINQ. The same query gets the desired result in VB, but in C# it throws an exception

> Specified cast is not valid.

I know C# is more strongly typed, but I can't find the difference here except `x.Field(Of Date?)("ReciveDate")` compare to `x.Field<DateTime?>("ReciveDate")`. Also, when I change the VB query to `DateTime?` it works properly.

I would be grateful for your advice.

**VB.NET**

```
Public Shared Function TeamContractServiceIncome(ByRef WipDatatable As DataTable, ByVal specificDate As DateTime) As Integer
    Dim contractSrv As Integer = WipDatatable.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(x) x.Field(Of Date?)("ReciveDate") = specificDate.Date _
                                                             ).Sum(Function(x) x.Field(Of Integer?)("Income"))
    Return contractSrv
End Function
```

**C#**

```
  public static int? GetDayShotefPerformance(ref DataTable dtToSearch, DateTime day)
    {
        int? shotef = dtToSearch.AsEnumerable().Where(x =>  x.Field<DateTime?>("ReciveDate")== day.Date).Sum
            (x => x.Field<int?>("Income"));
        return shotef;
    }
```

**UPDATE (still there is no solution)**

made some tests, also that throws the same exception, and i cant understand why:

```
 public static int? GetDayShotefPerformance(ref DataTable dtToSearch, DateTime day)
        {
            var shotef = dtToSearch.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<DateTime?>("ReciveDate").HasValue).Sum
                (x => x.Field<int?>("Income"));
            return shotef;
        }
```

Comment: what is the point of that first line which converts a date to string then back to date ?

Comment: How did you set Option Strict in the VB.NET app?

Comment: @ Plutonix, get only date from datetime

Comment: `specificDate.Date` would do that

Comment: Rather than declare `shotef` as an `int?` use `var`. It's still strongly typed but you let the compiler choose the right type (though that might not be the problem here). If you break down the LINQ into sub queries, one per statement you'll be able to see which part is causing the error.

Comment: Is the "ReciveDate" column actually a nullable datetime? Similarly is "Income" a nullable int?

Comment: @ChrisF - yes there are nulls in both of them.